# web scraping java beginner

Tags: java, web-scraping, html-parsing, webharvest, htmlcleaner

I am new to Java, I would like to become really good in web scraping and parsing data

Are there any sites related to web scraping that would help me understand the how the APIs like htmcleaner, web-harvest, htmlparser work??

I'm still not proficient enough in Java to look at their Javadocs and understand how all their methods work, and cannot find Java code examples(tutorials) on the web that would help me.

Comment: Make sure you have a good understanding of the basic Java API before you get started. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you try with this library: [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)?

The cookbook introduction is a good place where to start or you can go straight to the other specific code examples if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the examples at:

- http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php
- http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/usage.php
- http://chasethedevil.blogspot.com/2006/05/java-html-parsing-example-with.html

Maybe those can be of some help?